# Reducing "If, EsleIf, EndIf" statements in Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

Though I have enjoyed reading this website, this is my first post.
I have several "If, EsleIf, EndIf" statements in Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) - below are just a few. Is there a way to reduce the amount of typing, as well as to speed-up the process.

```
If Range("D18").Value = Range("L18").Value Or Range("D18").Value = Range("M18").Value Then
    Rows("19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("D18").Value <> Range("L18").Value Then
    Rows("19").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("D20").Value = Range("L20").Value Or Range("D20").Value = Range("M20").Value Then
    Rows("21").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("D20").Value <> Range("L20").Value Then
    Rows("21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

If Range("D22").Value = Range("L22").Value Or Range("D22").Value = Range("M22").Value Then
    Rows("23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("D22").Value <> Range("L22").Value Then
    Rows("23").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next way:

```
Sub MoreCompactCode()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastR = sh.Range("D" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row ' last row in D:D
  'if you do  not need to iterate up to the last cel you simple use lastR =   22 'last row to be iterated
  
  For i = 18 To lastR Step 2
        If sh.Range("D" & i).Value = Range("L" & i).Value Or sh.Range("D" & i).Value = sh.Range("M" & i).Value Then
            sh.rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ElseIf sh.Range("D" & i).Value <> sh.Range("L" & i).Value Then
           sh.rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

But being an event, it looks strange to iterate between all the range you show. Your code does not use `Target`. You probably should use a code like the above suggested one, **once** and then everything should be compared with `Target` in terms of `Offset`. I do not know what you really try doing and when the event should be triggered, to show you how (exactly) to proceed.

And `sh` should be `Me`, without any declaration. `Me` refers the current/active sheet in this event context.

I think, you can try the next event, which is triggered if a cell of D:D column, from  an even row is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 And Target.row Mod 2 = 0 Then 'to be triggered only for changes in column D:D, for even rows
        If Target.Value = Target.Offset(, 8).Value Or Target.Value = Target.Offset(, 9).Value Then
              Me.rows(Target.row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
          ElseIf Target.Value <> Target.Offset(, 8).Value Then
             Me.rows(Target.row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
          End If
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want it being triggered even if a cell in columns L:L, or M:M will be changed, the code can be adapted to do what you want.

Comment: I apologize for the late response - a family issue. Thank you both for your assistance! On the second option, is there a way to set it for a Range (only to row 36).

Comment: I figured it out. I placed "If Target.Row >= 18 And Target.Row <= 33 Then" before Fane's code.